# Error on Lookup

Tags: trigger, lookup

i have a new problem, I receive the error message

List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject  Trigger.MoveAtt: line 9, column 1

for the following trigger.

```
trigger MoveAtt on Attachment (after insert) {

    List<Id> forDeletionIds = new List<Id>();
    for (Attachment a : trigger.new){
    String parentIdString = String.valueof(a.parentId);
    if (parentIdString.substring(0,3) == '00T'){
        System.debug(a.parentId);
        if(Task.WhatId != null){
            if(Customer_Document__c.Task_ID__c != null){
            Customer_Document__c parent1 = [SELECT Id  FROM Customer_Document__c WHERE Task_ID__c = :a.parentId and CreatedDate__c = :a.CreatedDate ];
        if (parent1.Id  != null){
            Attachment body = [SELECT Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id = :a.Id];
            Attachment newA = New Attachment(
                Name = a.Name,
                Body = body.Body,
                Description = 'Email Attachment from ' + date.today(),
                OwnerId = a.OwnerId,
                ParentId = parent1.Id
            );
        }} 
        task parent = [SELECT Id,WhoId  FROM Task WHERE Id = :a.parentId];
        if (parent.WhoId  != null){
            Attachment body = [SELECT Body FROM Attachment WHERE Id = :a.Id];
            Attachment newA = New Attachment(
                Name = a.Name,
                Body = body.Body,
                Description = 'Email Attachment from ' + date.today(),
                OwnerId = a.OwnerId,
                ParentId = parent.WhoId
            );
            insert newA;
            forDeletionIds.add(a.Id);
        }
      }
    }
List<Attachment> forDeletion = [SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE Id IN :forDeletionIds];
delete forDeletion;
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the list for deletion should be like this `List<Attachment> forDeletionIds = new List<Attachment>();`, also the delete operation should be like this:

```
forDeletionIds.add(a);

List<Attachment> forDeletion = [SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE Id IN :forDeletionIds]; delete forDeletion;
```

**Updated**

Once you fill in the forDeletionIds object you don't need to retrieve the attachments again, just delete the attachments like this: `delete forDeletionIds;`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Ruslan, thx for this, but the deletion already works exactly as expected, so no need to work on this. Only problem i have is to get the id from the customer_document__c (custom object) This Customer_Document__c will be created exactly, when new task is created, therefore, the createdDate will be the same, and the creation of customer_document__c is working fine as well.

Comment: Ok, then I agree @Sander de Jong's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the condition WHERE Task_ID__c = :a.parentId and CreatedDate__c = :a.CreatedDate returns more than one record.

Comment: Hi Sander, yes, but i have no clue why this happens, do you have? As i wrote to Ruslan, the customer_document__c is created at the same time, the task/attachment is created. and therefore, there can´t be more then one from my perspective. maybe, i should add the second trigger, which will create the customer_document__c in parallel

Comment: Does the error occur (1) while using Salesforce or (2) while running the unit tests? If (2) then please share the unit test source code with us.

Comment: The error occur in salesforce, as i am working in sandbox

Comment: Do you have any more idea of what could be missing?

Comment: Run the query in the Developer Console, to see which records fulfill the query.

Comment: I am new to Apex Trigger, Can you please explain how to run in developer console on a trigger?

Comment: I didn't mean the whole trigger, just the query. Find out why you are getting more than one result from the query. As to how to use Developer Console for running queries, use help + Google.